# whate is the reasons that make multilayer perceptron with backpropagation algorithm classify all samples to one class

Tags: neural-network

I need a help with neural network task i applied  multilayer perceptron with backpropagation algorithm ,i am sure that all steps of training and learning are completely right but the problem is that testing step always classify all the samples to one class .
my output layer have 3 neurons and the result of output layer of each sample are so close so it always map to one class.
i tried to change the value of learning rate and the number of iterations but it's not working.

Comment: How do you initialize your weights? What framework/library are you using?

Comment: I initialized them random then i tried to  initialized  to 0.1 but not work 
and i use visual c#

Comment: Are you using One vs All method to determine which class to refer to?

Comment: i classify the sample based on the max value of the output layer , the max of the 3 neurons

Comment: Maybe you should get more data for training?)

Comment: I have 150 samples i use 90 for training and 40 for testing 
i use Iris data from this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set then i normalized them

Comment: Which technics are you using to normalize data? What MSE do you get after training? Can you plot a graph with numbers of epochs on X axe and Mean square error on Y axe?

Comment: I have 4 features to each sample , i get the average for each feature (get the average for feature 1 and the average of feature 2 and so on ) then subtract it from each feature for every sample 
after that i get the max number for each feature then divide each feature by its own max

Comment: plot graph http://postimg.org/image/ibw3gs5lh/

Comment: Looks like you have some problems with training algorithm, specifically with high bias. Your plot is a straight line. It should decrease exponentially with the numbers of iterations.

Comment: I generate bias randomly for each neuron its rang from 0 to 1

Comment: Not skilled in this field so handle following with prejudice but:  are your features enough for classification (there should be significant distinction between class and non class member images)?  do you have enough neurons for training set? (over training of neural network) is your neural network architecture capable of doing this task? (number of layers,number of neurons per layer,interconnections...) try to examine these sub-question and the answer may be found, if not you should at least add the network layout diagram to your question and specify features used with examples